# Error using Process.Start()

Tags: vb.net, filepath, process.start, working-directory, win32exception

I am trying to run sysprep from a vb.net application, and even though the path and file name are confirmed accurate, it is returning that it can not find the file. I've tried using process.start, declaring as a new process, declaring the path separate from the file name. Here is the code as I would like it to be written, maybe someone could try it out and see if they come up with a solution?

```
Private Sub btnsysp_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnsysp.Click
    Dim P As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
    P.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    P.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Windows\System32\sysprep\"
    P.StartInfo.FileName = "sysprep.exe"
    P.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: Permissions problems? If you move everything out of C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32 ?

Comment: Change the Target CPU setting on your project to AnyCPU so you don't get redirected to c:\windows\syswow64.  Which doesn't have sysprep.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just stumbled uppon the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187.aspx

> The %windir%\System32 directory is reserved for 64-bit applications. Most DLL file names were not >changed when 64-bit versions of the DLLs were created, so 32-bit versions of the DLLs are stored in a >different directory. WOW64 hides this difference by using a file system redirector.

What happens is that your launch request (from a 32-bit process) is being redirected to `%windir%\SysWOW64\sysprep\sysprep.exe`. Since there's no 32-bit version of this particular executable on SysWOW64 the launch fails.

The easiest way to bypass this problem is using reference to `%windir%\SysNative\sysprep\sysprep.exe` instead of `%windir%\System32\sysprep\sysprep.exe` which is what you have.

Comment: Thank you! I used the sysnative path and that worked. Thanks great explanation as well.