# File not found while creating process VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, process, file-not-found

I'm getting this error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified

   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)

   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
```

While executing this code:

```
Dim dnscmdString As String = DNSServer + " /RecordDelete " + dnszone + " " + server + " A " + IPAddress + " /f"

    Dim DNSCMD As New Process
    DNSCMD.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    DNSCMD.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    DNSCMD.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Windows\System32\dnscmd.exe"
    DNSCMD.StartInfo.Arguments = dnscmdString
    DNSCMD.Start()
    DNSCMD.WaitForExit(10000)
    Dim exitCode As Integer = DNSCMD.ExitCode
```

I know that the file is there, the file exists.

I know also that the process can work only specifying "dnscmd" on the filename.

Comment: Maybe a 32/64 bit redirect is going? If your process is running as 32 bit on a 64 bit machine it may be redirected to SysWow64 and so the file doesn't exist?

Comment: Try replacing "System32" with "SysNative" in process Filename property. If it works, check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708242/error-using-process-start/20709166#20709166) or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for further explanation.

Comment: @SomeNickName Unfortunately, it does not work. Shouldn't it work when I launch it through the "Run" Dialogue? it doesn't seem to be a SysNative folder under %windir%.

Comment: No, SysNative is the way to tell the OS to not reddirect the call to SysWoW64 when you're using a 32-bit application and want to access system32 (which is for 64-bit processes) , there is no real SysNative folder inside Windows\ , but in that way the call reaches the system32 folder which is what you wanted.

I see you already found a fix to your problem, but anyway...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I needed to set the application to x64 in order to recognize the "SysNative" bypass, and now it is finding the dnscmd.exe file under the SysNative folder (it could be SysWOW64 or System32).

Thanks for the Help!!!